# Connecting to many kubernetes services from local machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

From my local machine I would like to be able to `port forward` to many services in a cluster.
For example I have services of name `serviceA-type1`, `serviceA-type2`, `serviceA-type3`... etc. None of these services are accessible externally but can be accessed using the `kubectl port-forward` command. However there are so many services, that port forwarding to each is unfeasible.

Is it possible to create some kind of proxy service in kubernetes that would allow me to connect to any of the `serviceA-typeN` services by specifying the them in a URL? I would like to be able to `port-forward` to the proxy service from my local machine and it would then forward the requests to the `serviceA-typeN` services.

So for example, if I have set up a port forward on 8080 to this proxy, then the URL to access the `serviceA-type1` service might look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/serviceA-type1/path/to/endpoint?a=1
```

I could maybe create a small application that would do this but does kubernetes provide this functionality already?

Comment: Have to tried ingress?

Comment: Which local kubernetes cluster is used? Like minikube or desktop docker with kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl proxy` command provides this functionality.

Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls

Answer (score 0):

Good option is to use `Ingrees` to achieve it.

[Read more about what Ingress is](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Main concepts are:

> - Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.
> - An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based virtual hosting.
> - An Ingress controller is responsible for fulfilling the Ingress, usually with a load balancer, though it may also configure your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic.
> - An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type `Service.Type=NodePort` or `Service.Type=LoadBalancer`.

In Kubernetes we have 4 types of `Services` and the default service type is `Cluster IP` which means the service is only reachable within the cluster.`Ingress` exposes your service outside the cluster so `ingress` acts as the entry point into your cluster.

If you plan to move to cloud (I assume you will, because all applications are going to work in cloud in future) with `Ingress`, it will be compatible with cloud services and eventually will save time and will be easier to migrate from local environment.

---

To start with `ingress` you need to install an [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers) first.
There are [different ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers) which you can use.

You can start with most common [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) which is supported by kubernetes community.

If you're using a `minikube` than it can be enabled as an addon - [see here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller)

Once you have installed `ingress` in your cluster, you need to create a rule to have it work. [Simple fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) is an example with two services and `path` based routing to it.